# Python glob query

Tags: python

I am trying to learn Python using tutorials. I came across this code:

```
quote.extend(['/%s' % f for f in glob.glob('test/test/'+`doc`+'.*.doc')])
```

Does this mean a variable named quote is appending / extending `test/test/1.doc` and so on? What does `/%s' % f for f` mean here?

Comment: `'/%s' % f` is a string formating

Comment: replacing `f` with `filename` would probably make this code a bit easier to read...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine it like this:

```
quote.extend([('/%s' % f) for f in glob.glob('test/test/'+`doc`+'.*.doc')])
```

So:

- for each `f` in the iterator returned by `glob.glob()`,
- which is a string built from `"/" + f` (see [String Formatting Operations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations))
- will be added to a list (built by a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions))
- which will then be added to the already existing list `quote`.

Also,

```
`doc`
```

is the same as `repr(doc)` (and this syntax is deprecated; it's illegal in Python 3).

So you could also write this as

```
newfiles = []
for f in glob.glob('test/test/'+ repr(doc) + '.*.doc'):
    newfiles.append("/" + f)
quote.extend(newfiles)
```

which can be simplified to

```
for f in glob.glob('test/test/'+ repr(doc) + '.*.doc'):
    quote.append("/" + f)
```

Answer (score 0):

`quote` is a list which is extended by another list, which is dynamically created using `list comprehensons`. [Here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) are the details in the python doc. A list comprehension looks like

```
[x for x in foo]
```

`"/%s"` is called string formatting. Here again the doc concerning [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)

Basically `glob.glob()` looks up all files matching that pattern given, the string formatting operation adds a leading / and the list comprehension forms all the string to a list which is then appended to `quote`